# Snap scroll to another div that is set to snap tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a home component and I want to snap it using TailwindCSS Scroll Snap Utilities but it does not seem to work, I have added snap-start inside section1 :

```
import Section1 from "./section1";
import Sections from "./sections";

function HomeComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen overflow-scroll">
        <Section1 />
        <div className="snap-start no-scrollbar snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-full mx-auto overflow-scroll scroll-smooth">
          <Sections />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

The current result is section1 is fixed and there is no scroll happening, I do not know what I am doing here

Section1

```
  return (
    <div className={`snap-start ${imageIndex === images.length  ? "opacity-0" : "opacity-100"} `}>
      {images.map((img, index) => (
        <section
          key={index}
          className="relative h-screen flex"
          style={{ opacity: index === imageIndex ? 1 : 0 }}
          ref={index === images.length - 1 ? ref : null} // Apply ref to the last element
        >
          <div className="relative flex">
            <Image
              alt="Mountains"
              src={img}
              placeholder="blur"
              quality={100}
              className="fixed h-screen object-cover w-full top-0"
            />
          </div>
        </section>
      ))}
      <div className="fixed left-10 top-1/3  flex items-center text-[30px] md:text-[50px] font-bold text-gray-100 bg-black p-3">
        <Image
          src={Logo}
          alt="fourseason logo"
          width={0}
          height={0}
          className="w-[30px] md:w-[70px] mr-1"
        />
        FourSeason
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```